# EhCache with RIM replication takes a long time to startup

Tags: java, tomcat, ehcache

I am using a replicated RIM Ehcache deployed in a Tomcat 6 environment with 2 nodes in the addresses 192.168.104.131 and 192.168.104.132. Starting one node takes forever before throwing SocketException errors (as it should be as the other node is not up). If I start the two of them they don't seem to connect with each other.

My ehcache.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<ehcache xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="ehcache.xsd"
     name="AppLinkCacheManger" updateCheck="false" monitoring="off"
     dynamicConfig="false" maxBytesLocalHeap="30M" maxBytesLocalDisk="100M"> 

<diskStore path="java.io.tmpdir"/>

<cacheManagerPeerProviderFactory class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheManagerPeerProviderFactory"
    properties="peerDiscovery=manual,
        rmiUrls=//192.168.104.131:40001/deleteEntries|//192.168.104.131:40001/shortCache|//192.168.104.131:40001/longCache"
    propertySeparator="," />

<cacheManagerPeerListenerFactory
     class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheManagerPeerListenerFactory"
     properties="hostName=192.168.104.132,
                 port=40001,
                 socketTimeoutMillis=2000"/>


   <cache name="deleteEntries" eternal="false" 
        timeToIdleSeconds="180" timeToLiveSeconds="600"
        memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LFU" statistics="true">
        <cacheEventListenerFactory
            class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheReplicatorFactory"
            properties="replicateAsynchronously=true, replicatePuts=true, replicateUpdates=true, replicateUpdatesViaCopy=false, replicateRemovals=true " />
        <bootstrapCacheLoaderFactory class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMIBootstrapCacheLoaderFactory"
            properties="bootstrapAsynchronously=true, maximumChunkSizeBytes=5000000" propertySeparator="," />
        <persistence strategy="localTempSwap"/>
</cache>

<cache name="shortCache" eternal="false" 
        timeToIdleSeconds="180" timeToLiveSeconds="600"
        memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LFU" statistics="true">
        <cacheEventListenerFactory
            class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheReplicatorFactory"
            properties="replicateAsynchronously=true, replicatePuts=true, replicateUpdates=true, replicateUpdatesViaCopy=false, replicateRemovals=true " />
        <bootstrapCacheLoaderFactory class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMIBootstrapCacheLoaderFactory"
            properties="bootstrapAsynchronously=true, maximumChunkSizeBytes=5000000" propertySeparator="," />
        <persistence strategy="localTempSwap"/>
</cache>

<cache name="longCache" eternal="false" 
        timeToIdleSeconds="100000" timeToLiveSeconds="700000" 
        statistics="true" memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LFU">
        <cacheEventListenerFactory class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheReplicatorFactory"
            properties="replicateAsynchronously=true, replicatePuts=true, replicateUpdates=true, replicateUpdatesViaCopy=false, replicateRemovals=true " />
        <bootstrapCacheLoaderFactory class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMIBootstrapCacheLoaderFactory"
            properties="bootstrapAsynchronously=true, maximumChunkSizeBytes=5000000" propertySeparator="," />
        <persistence strategy="localTempSwap"/>
</cache>
```

Looking at the JVM threads the app seems to be stuck creating the socket?!?!

```
"main" prio=10 tid=0x08a9cc00 nid=0x380 runnable [0xf765e000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
        - locked <0xd2a27b40> (a java.net.SocksSocketImpl)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:425)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:208)
        at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIDirectSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIDirectSocketFactory.java:40)
        at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIMasterSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIMasterSocketFactory.java:146)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:613)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(TCPChannel.java:216)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(TCPChannel.java:202)
        at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.newCall(UnicastRef.java:340)
        at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.list(Unknown Source)
        at net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheManagerPeerListener.startRegistry(RMICacheManagerPeerListener.java:323)
        at net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheManagerPeerListener.init(RMICacheManagerPeerListener.java:205)
        at net.sf.ehcache.event.CacheManagerEventListenerRegistry.init(CacheManagerEventListenerRegistry.java:104)
        at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.doInit(CacheManager.java:450)
        at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.init(CacheManager.java:377)
```

The ehcache logs (notice the jumps on the logs where the app got stuck)

```
681 [main] DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.config.ConfigurationFactory  - Configuring ehcache from URL: file:/opt/criticalpath/ps/webapps/cp/WEB-INF/classes/ehcache.xml
681 [main] DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.config.ConfigurationFactory  - Configuring ehcache from InputStream
1285 [main] DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.config.BeanHandler  - Ignoring ehcache attribute xmlns:xsi
1285 [main] DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.config.BeanHandler  - Ignoring ehcache attribute xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation
1290 [main] DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.config.DiskStoreConfiguration  - Disk Store Path: /opt/criticalpath/ps/temp
1325 [main] DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager  - Creating new CacheManager with default config
1332 [main] DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.util.PropertyUtil  - propertiesString is null.
1344 [main] INFO net.sf.ehcache.pool.sizeof.filter.AnnotationSizeOfFilter  - Using regular expression provided through VM argument net.sf.ehcache.pool.sizeof.ignore.pattern for IgnoreSizeOf annotation : ^.*cache\..*IgnoreSizeOf$
1350 [main] INFO net.sf.ehcache.pool.sizeof.AgentLoader  - Located valid 'tools.jar' at '/opt/criticalpath/jdk1.7.0_25/jre/../lib/tools.jar'
1361 [main] INFO net.sf.ehcache.pool.sizeof.JvmInformation  - Detected JVM data model settings of: 32-Bit HotSpot JVM
1611 [main] INFO net.sf.ehcache.pool.sizeof.AgentLoader  - Extracted agent jar to temporary file /opt/criticalpath/ps/temp/ehcache-sizeof-agent2399881412311938585.jar
1611 [main] INFO net.sf.ehcache.pool.sizeof.AgentLoader  - Trying to load agent @ /opt/criticalpath/ps/temp/ehcache-sizeof-agent2399881412311938585.jar
1616 [main] INFO net.sf.ehcache.pool.impl.DefaultSizeOfEngine  - using Agent sizeof engine
1629 [main] DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.config.ConfigurationHelper  - No CacheManagerEventListenerFactory class specified. Skipping...
1631 [main] DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.util.PropertyUtil  - Value found for hostName: localhost
1631 [main] DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.util.PropertyUtil  - Value found for port: 40001
1631 [main] DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.util.PropertyUtil  - Value found for remoteObjectPort: null
1631 [main] DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.util.PropertyUtil  - Value found for socketTimeoutMillis: 2000
1635 [main] WARN net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheManagerPeerListener  - Explicitly setting the listener hostname to 'localhost' is not recommended. It will only work if all CacheManager peers are on the same machine.
1639 [main] DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.util.PropertyUtil  - Value found for peerDiscovery: manual
1639 [main] DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.util.PropertyUtil  - Value found for rmiUrls: //192.168.104.131:40001/deleteEntries|//192.168.104.131:40001/shortCache|//192.168.104.131:40001/longCache
1639 [main] DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheManagerPeerProviderFactory  - Registering peer //192.168.104.131:40001/deleteEntries
1640 [main] DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheManagerPeerProviderFactory  - Registering peer //192.168.104.131:40001/shortCache
1640 [main] DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheManagerPeerProviderFactory  - Registering peer //192.168.104.131:40001/longCache
190679 [main] DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheManagerPeerListener  - 0 RMICachePeers bound in registry for RMI listener
190679 [main] INFO net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager  - The CacheManager shutdown hook is enabled because net.sf.ehcache.enableShutdownHook is set to true.
190765 [main] DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.util.PropertyUtil  - Value found for replicatePuts: true
190765 [main] DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.util.PropertyUtil  - Value found for replicatePutsViaCopy: null
190765 [main] DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.util.PropertyUtil  - Value found for replicateUpdates: true
190765 [main] DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.util.PropertyUtil  - Value found for replicateUpdatesViaCopy: false
190765 [main] DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.util.PropertyUtil  - Value found for replicateRemovals: true
190765 [main] DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.util.PropertyUtil  - Value found for replicateAsynchronously: true
190765 [main] DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.util.PropertyUtil  - Value found for asynchronousReplicationIntervalMillis: null
190765 [main] DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.util.PropertyUtil  - Value found for asynchronousReplicationMaximumBatchSize: null
190782 [main] DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.util.PropertyUtil  - Value found for bootstrapAsynchronously: true
190782 [main] DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.util.PropertyUtil  - Value found for maximumChunkSizeBytes: 5000000
190784 [main] DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.Cache  - CacheWriter factory not configured. Skipping...
190792 [main] DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.config.ConfigurationHelper  - No CacheExceptionHandlerFactory class specified. Skipping...
190792 [main] DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.util.PropertyUtil  - Value found for replicatePuts: true
190792 [main] DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.util.PropertyUtil  - Value found for replicatePutsViaCopy: null
190792 [main] DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.util.PropertyUtil  - Value found for replicateUpdates: true
190792 [main] DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.util.PropertyUtil  - Value found for replicateUpdatesViaCopy: false
190792 [main] DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.util.PropertyUtil  - Value found for replicateRemovals: true
190793 [main] DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.util.PropertyUtil  - Value found for replicateAsynchronously: true
190793 [main] DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.util.PropertyUtil  - Value found for asynchronousReplicationIntervalMillis: null
190793 [main] DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.util.PropertyUtil  - Value found for asynchronousReplicationMaximumBatchSize: null
190793 [main] DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.util.PropertyUtil  - Value found for bootstrapAsynchronously: true
190793 [main] DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.util.PropertyUtil  - Value found for maximumChunkSizeBytes: 5000000
190793 [main] DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.Cache  - CacheWriter factory not configured. Skipping...
190793 [main] DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.config.ConfigurationHelper  - No CacheExceptionHandlerFactory class specified. Skipping...
190793 [main] DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.util.PropertyUtil  - Value found for replicatePuts: true
190793 [main] DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.util.PropertyUtil  - Value found for replicatePutsViaCopy: null
190793 [main] DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.util.PropertyUtil  - Value found for replicateUpdates: true
190793 [main] DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.util.PropertyUtil  - Value found for replicateUpdatesViaCopy: false
190793 [main] DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.util.PropertyUtil  - Value found for replicateRemovals: true
190793 [main] DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.util.PropertyUtil  - Value found for replicateAsynchronously: true
190793 [main] DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.util.PropertyUtil  - Value found for asynchronousReplicationIntervalMillis: null
190793 [main] DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.util.PropertyUtil  - Value found for asynchronousReplicationMaximumBatchSize: null
190794 [main] DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.util.PropertyUtil  - Value found for bootstrapAsynchronously: true
190794 [main] DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.util.PropertyUtil  - Value found for maximumChunkSizeBytes: 5000000
190794 [main] DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.Cache  - CacheWriter factory not configured. Skipping...
190795 [main] DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.config.ConfigurationHelper  - No CacheExceptionHandlerFactory class specified. Skipping...
190795 [main] DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.Cache  - No BootstrapCacheLoaderFactory class specified. Skipping...
190795 [main] DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.Cache  - CacheWriter factory not configured. Skipping...
190795 [main] DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.config.ConfigurationHelper  - No CacheExceptionHandlerFactory class specified. Skipping...
190847 [main] DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.store.MemoryStore  - Initialized net.sf.ehcache.store.MemoryStore for longCache
190882 [main] DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.DiskStorePathManager  - Using diskstore path /opt/criticalpath/ps/temp
190882 [main] DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.DiskStorePathManager  - Holding exclusive lock on /opt/criticalpath/ps/temp/.ehcache-diskstore.lock
190883 [main] DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.store.disk.DiskStorageFactory  - Failed to delete file long%0043ache.index
190903 [main] DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.store.disk.DiskStorageFactory  - Matching data file missing (or empty) for index file. Deleting index file /opt/criticalpath/ps/temp/long%0043ache.index
190903 [main] DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.store.disk.DiskStorageFactory  - Failed to delete file long%0043ache.index
190919 [main] DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.Cache  - Initialised cache: longCache
190920 [main] DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheManagerPeerListener  - Adding to RMI listener
190922 [Bootstrap Thread for cache longCache] DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMIBootstrapCacheLoader  - Attempting to acquire cache peers for cache longCache to bootstrap from. Will wait up to 0ms for cache to join cluster.
190923 [Bootstrap Thread for cache longCache] DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheManagerPeerProvider  - Lookup URL //192.168.104.131:40001/longCache
190929 [Bootstrap Thread for cache longCache] DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.distribution.ManualRMICacheManagerPeerProvider  - Looking up rmiUrl //192.168.104.131:40001/longCache through exception Connection refused to host: 192.168.104.131; nested exception is: 
        java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused. This may be normal if a node has gone offline. Or it may indicate network connectivity difficulties
java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 192.168.104.131; nested exception is: 
        java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:619)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(TCPChannel.java:216)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(TCPChannel.java:202)
        at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.newCall(UnicastRef.java:340)
        at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.lookup(Unknown Source)
        at java.rmi.Naming.lookup(Naming.java:101)
        at net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheManagerPeerProvider.lookupRemoteCachePeer(RMICacheManagerPeerProvider.java:127)
        at net.sf.ehcache.distribution.ManualRMICacheManagerPeerProvider.listRemoteCachePeers(ManualRMICacheManagerPeerProvider.java:95)
        at net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMIBootstrapCacheLoader.listRemoteCachePeers(RMIBootstrapCacheLoader.java:245)
        at net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMIBootstrapCacheLoader.acquireCachePeers(RMIBootstrapCacheLoader.java:198)
        at net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMIBootstrapCacheLoader.doLoad(RMIBootstrapCacheLoader.java:132)
        at net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMIBootstrapCacheLoader$BootstrapThread.run(RMIBootstrapCacheLoader.java:107)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:425)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:208)
        at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIDirectSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIDirectSocketFactory.java:40)
        at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIMasterSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIMasterSocketFactory.java:146)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:613)
        ... 11 more
192010 [Bootstrap Thread for cache longCache] DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMIBootstrapCacheLoader  - cache peers: []
192011 [Bootstrap Thread for cache longCache] DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMIBootstrapCacheLoader  - Empty list of cache peers for cache longCache. No cache peer to bootstrap from.
380030 [main] DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheManagerPeerListener  - 1 RMICachePeers bound in registry for RMI listener
380030 [main] DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.config.ConfigurationHelper  - CacheDecoratorFactory not configured. Skipping for 'longCache'.
380030 [main] DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.config.ConfigurationHelper  - CacheDecoratorFactory not configured for defaultCache. Skipping for 'longCache'.
380033 [main] DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.store.MemoryStore  - Eviction selection miss. Selected element is null
380034 [main] INFO net.sf.ehcache.pool.impl.DefaultSizeOfEngine  - using Agent sizeof engine
380034 [main] DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.store.MemoryStore  - Initialized net.sf.ehcache.store.MemoryStore for deleteEntries
380035 [main] DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.store.disk.DiskStorageFactory  - Failed to delete file delete%0045ntries.index
380035 [main] DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.store.disk.DiskStorageFactory  - Matching data file missing (or empty) for index file. Deleting index file /opt/criticalpath/ps/temp/delete%0045ntries.index
380035 [main] DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.store.disk.DiskStorageFactory  - Failed to delete file delete%0045ntries.index
380036 [main] DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.Cache  - Initialised cache: deleteEntries
380036 [main] DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheManagerPeerListener  - Adding to RMI listener
380038 [Bootstrap Thread for cache deleteEntries] DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMIBootstrapCacheLoader  - Attempting to acquire cache peers for cache deleteEntries to bootstrap from. Will wait up to 0ms for cache to join cluster.
380038 [Bootstrap Thread for cache deleteEntries] DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheManagerPeerProvider  - Lookup URL //192.168.104.131:40001/deleteEntries
380040 [Bootstrap Thread for cache deleteEntries] DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.distribution.ManualRMICacheManagerPeerProvider  - Looking up rmiUrl //192.168.104.131:40001/deleteEntries through exception Connection refused to host: 192.168.104.131; nested exception is: 
        java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused. This may be normal if a node has gone offline. Or it may indicate network connectivity difficulties
java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 192.168.104.131; nested exception is: 
        java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:619)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(TCPChannel.java:216)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(TCPChannel.java:202)
        at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.newCall(UnicastRef.java:340)
        at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.lookup(Unknown Source)
        at java.rmi.Naming.lookup(Naming.java:101)
        at net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheManagerPeerProvider.lookupRemoteCachePeer(RMICacheManagerPeerProvider.java:127)
        at net.sf.ehcache.distribution.ManualRMICacheManagerPeerProvider.listRemoteCachePeers(ManualRMICacheManagerPeerProvider.java:95)
        at net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMIBootstrapCacheLoader.listRemoteCachePeers(RMIBootstrapCacheLoader.java:245)
        at net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMIBootstrapCacheLoader.acquireCachePeers(RMIBootstrapCacheLoader.java:198)
        at net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMIBootstrapCacheLoader.doLoad(RMIBootstrapCacheLoader.java:132)
        at net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMIBootstrapCacheLoader$BootstrapThread.run(RMIBootstrapCacheLoader.java:107)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:425)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:208)
        at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIDirectSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIDirectSocketFactory.java:40)
        at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIMasterSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIMasterSocketFactory.java:146)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:613)
        ... 11 more
381043 [Bootstrap Thread for cache deleteEntries] DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMIBootstrapCacheLoader  - cache peers: []
381043 [Bootstrap Thread for cache deleteEntries] DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMIBootstrapCacheLoader  - Empty list of cache peers for cache deleteEntries. No cache peer to bootstrap from.
569048 [main] DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheManagerPeerListener  - 2 RMICachePeers bound in registry for RMI listener
569048 [main] DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.config.ConfigurationHelper  - CacheDecoratorFactory not configured. Skipping for 'deleteEntries'.
569048 [main] DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.config.ConfigurationHelper  - CacheDecoratorFactory not configured for defaultCache. Skipping for 'deleteEntries'.
569049 [main] DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.store.MemoryStore  - Initialized net.sf.ehcache.store.MemoryStore for shortCache
569050 [main] DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.store.disk.DiskStorageFactory  - Failed to delete file short%0043ache.index
569050 [main] DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.store.disk.DiskStorageFactory  - Matching data file missing (or empty) for index file. Deleting index file /opt/criticalpath/ps/temp/short%0043ache.index
569050 [main] DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.store.disk.DiskStorageFactory  - Failed to delete file short%0043ache.index
569051 [main] DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.Cache  - Initialised cache: shortCache
569051 [main] DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheManagerPeerListener  - Adding to RMI listener
569052 [Bootstrap Thread for cache shortCache] DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMIBootstrapCacheLoader  - Attempting to acquire cache peers for cache shortCache to bootstrap from. Will wait up to 0ms for cache to join cluster.
569053 [Bootstrap Thread for cache shortCache] DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheManagerPeerProvider  - Lookup URL //192.168.104.131:40001/shortCache
569053 [Bootstrap Thread for cache shortCache] DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.distribution.ManualRMICacheManagerPeerProvider  - Looking up rmiUrl //192.168.104.131:40001/shortCache through exception Connection refused to host: 192.168.104.131; nested exception is: 
        java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused. This may be normal if a node has gone offline. Or it may indicate network connectivity difficulties
java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 192.168.104.131; nested exception is: 
        java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:619)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(TCPChannel.java:216)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(TCPChannel.java:202)
        at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.newCall(UnicastRef.java:340)
        at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.lookup(Unknown Source)
        at java.rmi.Naming.lookup(Naming.java:101)
        at net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheManagerPeerProvider.lookupRemoteCachePeer(RMICacheManagerPeerProvider.java:127)
        at net.sf.ehcache.distribution.ManualRMICacheManagerPeerProvider.listRemoteCachePeers(ManualRMICacheManagerPeerProvider.java:95)
        at net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMIBootstrapCacheLoader.listRemoteCachePeers(RMIBootstrapCacheLoader.java:245)
        at net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMIBootstrapCacheLoader.acquireCachePeers(RMIBootstrapCacheLoader.java:198)
        at net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMIBootstrapCacheLoader.doLoad(RMIBootstrapCacheLoader.java:132)
        at net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMIBootstrapCacheLoader$BootstrapThread.run(RMIBootstrapCacheLoader.java:107)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:425)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:208)
        at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIDirectSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIDirectSocketFactory.java:40)
        at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIMasterSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIMasterSocketFactory.java:146)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:613)
        ... 11 more
570056 [Bootstrap Thread for cache shortCache] DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMIBootstrapCacheLoader  - cache peers: []
570056 [Bootstrap Thread for cache shortCache] DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMIBootstrapCacheLoader  - Empty list of cache peers for cache shortCache. No cache peer to bootstrap from.
Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timeout waiting for Environment!
        at net.cp.nextel.applink.gamification.notifications.ListenerThread.waitForEnvironment(ListenerThread.java:142)
        at net.cp.nextel.applink.gamification.notifications.ListenerThread.run(ListenerThread.java:72)
758062 [main] DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheManagerPeerListener  - 3 RMICachePeers bound in registry for RMI listener
758062 [main] DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.config.ConfigurationHelper  - CacheDecoratorFactory not configured. Skipping for 'shortCache'.
758062 [main] DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.config.ConfigurationHelper  - CacheDecoratorFactory not configured for defaultCache. Skipping for 'shortCache'.
758063 [main] DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.store.MemoryStore  - Eviction selection miss. Selected element is null
758064 [main] DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.store.MemoryStore  - Eviction selection miss. Selected element is null
758064 [main] INFO net.sf.ehcache.pool.impl.DefaultSizeOfEngine  - using Agent sizeof engine
758067 [main] DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.store.MemoryStore  - Initialized net.sf.ehcache.store.NotifyingMemoryStore for paginationResults
758092 [main] DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.Cache  - Initialised cache: paginationResults
758092 [main] DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheManagerPeerListener  - Adding to RMI listener
758092 [main] DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheManagerPeerListener  - 3 RMICachePeers bound in registry for RMI listener
758092 [main] DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.config.ConfigurationHelper  - CacheDecoratorFactory not configured. Skipping for 'paginationResults'.
758092 [main] DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.config.ConfigurationHelper  - CacheDecoratorFactory not configured for defaultCache. Skipping for 'paginationResults'.
758109 [main] DEBUG org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/cp]  -  Starting filter 'GetUsernameFilter'
758112 [main] DEBUG org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/cp]  -  Starting filter '2WayFilter'
758113 [main] DEBUG org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/cp]  -  Starting filter 'LogContextFilter'
758114 [main] DEBUG org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/cp]  -  Starting filter 'Applink Template Patches Filter'
758125 [main] DEBUG org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/cp]  -  Starting filter 'UrlRewriteFilter'
758134 [main] INFO org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/cp]  - org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter INFO: status display enabled, path set to /applink-urlrewrite-status
758332 [main] INFO org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/cp]  - org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter INFO: loaded (conf ok)
758535 [main] INFO net.cp.ps.sdk.server.Server  - Presentation Server starting ....
758536 [main] INFO net.cp.ps.sdk.server.Server  - Mon Sep 02 06:48:14 CDT 2013
758625 [main] WARN net.cp.ps.sdk.util.distlocks.LockClient  - Distributed locking service not configured; locks will not be shared.
759112 [main] ERROR net.cp.ps.sdk.server.ServerConfig  - Cannot find or an error in the configuration: filter-maxdepthlevels/filter-maxdepthlevel
Sep 02, 2013 6:48:45 AM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11BaseProtocol start
INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-192.168.104.132-8080
Sep 02, 2013 6:48:45 AM org.apache.catalina.storeconfig.StoreLoader load
INFO: Find registry server-registry.xml at classpath resource
Sep 02, 2013 6:48:45 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 790104 ms
```

Any ideas why this can be happening? Any help would be greatly appreciated ...

Comment: Not sure about the connection issues, but FWIW I'm getting the massive pause with the same thread dump state in a successful scenario.

Comment: Seems like the delay for me was caused by DNS (reverse lookup?) - switching to IP address resolved that. Doesn't look like much help for you unfortunately.